# Why cant send mail through smtp server?

Tags: java, smtp, sendmail, hotmail

I try to send mail from hotmail to yahoo/gmail using code as below with 
**smtp.live.com or smtp-mail.outlook.com** but keep getting error :

```
String to = SendTo.getText();
String from = username;

        java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");    // i try smtp-mail.outlook.com also cant
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,passwd);
    }};

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,authenticator); //default session

        if(attachment.getText().isEmpty()){
              try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); //email message
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));     //setting header fields
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(subjectField.getText()); //subject line

            //mail body
            message.setText(TextArea.getText());
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, to);
            //host = smtp.live.com from=abc@hotmail.com to=def@gmail.com
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
```

ERROR:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
```

Comment: Please reformat exception to keep line breaks and make it easier to read.

Comment: solved: for hotmail use 

transport.connect(host,587,username,passwd);
  
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Answer (score 0):

Neither host `smtp.live.com` nor host `smtp-mail.outlook.com` appears to accept connections on port 465.

You should probably be using port 587 instead.